# Paging with a Drupal REST View?

Tags: drupal, rest, drupal-views

I have a Views 2 view in Drupal that returns JSON. I'd like to page through it using url args. How can I do this?

I tried stuff like `path?page=3` or `path?page=[3]` or `path/3` without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`path?page=3` is correct when dealing w/ a clean install of D6 and Views 2 using the display type Page.

If you are using the [Views Datasource](http://drupal.org/project/views_datasource) module, you can create a Page display and change the Style attribute to JSON data document. This uses the same pager system as above.

Please remember that `path` is equivalent to `path?page=0`. So if you don't have enough data to get to page 3, this might be the problem.

If this answer is not enough or you are using a different method of generating the JSON, please leave a comment and I'll adjust the answer accordingly.

Comment: Wow, I don't know how that wasn't working for me earlier. Good call.

Comment: Method for adding pager data to your JSON feed. https://www.drupal.org/node/905440